# Anaconda suggesting file path that does not exist

Tags: python, scipy, path, anaconda, featuretools

I am importing package A which is dependent on package B and getting an import error for something within package B. Despite lots of trying, I can't get the dependencies to match, so I want to just edit package B to fix the problem. The issue is that my current anaconda environment is tracing the error to a file path does not exist.

In particular, it thinks the error is in: `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py`

However, the actual path that exists is `/Users/USER/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py`

I really have no idea what is going on because there is no such file path so where could it be looking? Furthermore, I changed the file in the `python3.9` folder which had no effect. Any help would be great.

P.S. the underlying error here I was trying to fix is when trying to import `featuretools` I receive the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'float_factorial' from 'scipy._lib._util'` If anyone wants to tackle this too that'd be amazing ;)

Updated with full error traceback for the original import error:
[image]

Comment: You're not really supposed to be using any of the scipy modules that begin with an underscore.  Why are you using them?

Comment: @JohnGordon I’m not trying to use them but when importing featuretools it imports from those modules in scipy. I don’t know how to avoid it

Comment: Oh, those imports are coming from some other module?  Then please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon I just attached a screenshot of what I'm seeing. That python3.8 folder is nowhere to be found so I don't know what it's referencing. however I can bypass messing with the _util file if I could get the ImportError dealt with. thanks

Comment: Are you working inside of a virtual environment?

Comment: Env is anaconda base I think

Comment: anaconda is such a pain because you have 10 million packages in base. I would probably recommend (if possible) to create a new and empty environment (so to speak) and then put in it only what you actually need. This makes it easier to manage that one environment with the versions that you need (and that work :) ). I'm not so familiar with anaconda because I use miniconda but this should be possible in anaconda too, using the anaconda prompt or the anaconda gui tools (in miniconda `conda create --name MyNewEnv python=3.9` is the command I would use)

Comment: @topsail did this and seemed to fix it. Still confused on what even happened but thanks for the help!

Comment: when you check `conda list` in your base, what are the lines for `featuretools` and `scipy`?

Comment: ` I changed the file in the python3.9 folder` don't jsut change files of installed libraries. I would recommend you revert that change

Comment: Does `/opt/anaconda3` also not exists, or is it just the referenced `.py` file that does not exist?

Comment: Just to be sure ... make sure you are not simply not seeing hidden folders :) [Show-Hidden-Files-and-Folders-on-a-Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Show-Hidden-Files-and-Folders-on-a-Mac) Although changing the source code directly in a library sounds dire and may break other things by fixing this thing depending on what you change.